# Page redirecting to wrong url when table value null Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The Page by default redirects to `user/profilepicture/` either table value `$user->profile` pic is `null` or not.

```
if($this->session->userdata("user_id"))//If already logged in
    {
        $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
        $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
        //load the view
      if($user->profile_pic == null)
      {
         redirect(base_url().'user/profilepicture/'); 
      }else{
         redirect(base_url().'blog/');
      }
```

Comment: Your condition is wrong. use this if($data['user']->profile_pic == null)

Comment: gotcha, Thanks  for the help

Comment: mark my comment 'Useful'

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: At the start of my first comment on the left side, you will see the arrow. Click on the arrow to mark the comment as useful

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if($this->session->userdata("user_id"))//If already logged in
    {
        $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
       $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
        //load the view
      if( $data['user']['profile_pic'] == null && $data['user']['profile_pic']!= null)
      {
         redirect(base_url().'user/profilepicture/'); 
      }else{
         redirect(base_url().'blog/');
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if($this->session->userdata("user_id"))//If already logged in
    {
        $userID = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
        $data['user'] = $this->m_user->getRows($userID);
        //load the view
      if($user->profile_pic==null)
      {     
            $url = base_url().'user/profilepicture/';           
      }else{
            $url = base_url().'blog/';

      }
      //echo $url; just check url copy and paset with new tab it is working or not ?
      redirect($url);
```

Comment: The condition is wrong. `$user` variable is not initialized. Should use `$data['user']->profile_pic`